# SoapUI client side

Tags: java, web-services, groovy, soapui, autotools

I have a wsdl to connect
I set all the attribute sufficently.(SoapUI)
In SoapUI project runs very well.

In this stage how can I export the dynamic client for this?
Is there any script or any tools for this?

For example I want to send external request data to SoapUI and get response also put any folder to this response for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use soapui outside of soapui I would recommend utilizing testRunner. testRunner can be called via the cmd line. It can also be integrated with via junit and maven.

Here is a link to soapui's page where you can get more information on how to do this:
http://www.soapui.org/Test-Automation/functional-tests.html